# How to choose displayed text on Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I choose which property is displayed in Html.DropDownListFor for a some type?

For example I have the following class from which I want to select values

```
public partial class Artysta
    {
        public Artysci()
        {
            this.SpektaklArtysta = new HashSet<SpektaklArtysta>();
        }

    [Key]
    public int ArtystaID { get; set; }

    public string Imie { get; set; }

    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }        
}
```

Here is a generated code for edit View which sometimes displays **Imie** and from time to time **Nazwisko**.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@model Teatr.Models.SpektaklArtysta
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArtystaID, "Artysta", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ArtystaID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArtystaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

I would like to set displayed property to **Nazwisko**, how can I achieve that?

UPDATE:

Here is actual model that this View was generated.

```
public partial class SpektaklArtysta
    {
        public int SpektaklID { get; set; }

        public int ArtystaID { get; set; }

        public int RolaArtystyID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int SpektaklArtystaID { get; set; }

        public virtual Artysci Artysci { get; set; }

        public virtual RolaArtysty RolaArtysty { get; set; }

        public virtual Spektakle Spektakle { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean displays `Imie` - none of the code you have posted will display anything related to property `Imie` (or for `Nazwisko`). Its not clear what your trying to do (and in any case your `@Html.DropDownList()` does not work either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to actually pass a list of possible values to the dropdown list, for example like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArtystaID, new SelectList(Model.Artysci, "ArtystaID", "Nazwisko", 0))
```

It says: DropDownList setting models ArtystaID field, which is populated by models Artysci field, which is supposed to contain items that have key under `ArtystaID` field and display text under `Nazwisko` field (so, your Artysta class).

Now, your class doesn't have Artysci field, so you have to create it:

```
public partial class Artysta
    {
        public Artysci()
        {
            this.SpektaklArtysta = new HashSet<SpektaklArtysta>();
        }

    [Key]
    public int ArtystaID { get; set; }

    public string Imie { get; set; }

    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }      

    public List<Artysta> Artysci = ArtistRepository.GetAllArtists();
}
```

Or you can pass it directly in DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArtystaID, new SelectList(ArtistRepository.GetAllArtists(), "ArtystaID", "Nazwisko", 0))
```

Oh, and just a personal note: I know it's probably not your choice, unless you are a lead/sole developer, but please use English names for your classes, variables etc., it will be much easier if in the future someone else will have to work on your code, and they might not speak Polish ;)

Comment: I have updated the question post with model class that this view was generated for. Current code works fine (displays all possible values) but sometimes displayed text is Imie and sometimes Nazwisko. I'll check approach that you have suggested in a moment. About Polish names, I'm doing a university course where doctor requires Polish names, grinds my gears ;] All my codebase is always in English but this time I had no choice.

Comment: Simple and smooth! Works like a charm. It's a shame that I can't alter which values are displayed for automatically generated code but well.

Comment: As in which values go to the dropdown? In `new SelectList()` you can do a Linq query on the data source: `Model.Artysci.Where(artysta => artysta.Nazwisko.EndsWith("ski")` or whatever filtering you want, or do some modifications, like: `Model.Artysci.Select(artysta => new Artysta{ArtystaID = artysta.ArtystaID, Imie = artysta.Imie, Nazwisko = "Pan " + artysta.Nazwisko})`

Answer (score 2):

One good option for you is to use the `DropDownList` as following

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownId", Model.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = item.ArtystaID.ToString(),
    Text = item.Nazwisko.ToString(),
     Selected = "select" == item.ArtystaID.ToString() ? true : false
}))
```

Hope that answers your request!

Comment: I do not know, but if the Model has more than 1 item, I am guessing it is relevant.

Comment: If it had more than one item your code wouldn't work anyway. And why do you suggest `DropDownListFor` but then post code for `DropDownList`? And you have not bound the dropdownlist to a model property so it wont be bound!

Comment: I have updated my answer, it is not `DropDownListFor`, but `DropDownList`. The `Model` is the `IEnumerable<T>` which contains the items which are used to create the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, which is the datasource of the `DropDownList`

Comment: Look at OP's view code - the model is `@model Teatr.Models.SpektaklArtysta`, not `IEnumerable`! (but don't worry about it - OP's code makes no sense at all)

Comment: Well I have answered the question, generally speaking, but did not fix the code he posted.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this code is generated automatically by Visual Studio when choosing  "New Controller -> MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework -> Select for example SpektaklArtysta model". Saying that it doesn't make sense is a bit ignorant, try it yourself and you will see that such code works even tho it has "null" as selection list. This code works and populates dropdownlist with items without a problem. Only problem is the displayed text.

Comment: I really don't know why i got a down-vote, since the answer is correct.

Comment: I don't know who down voted you but your answer is partially correct in this scenario. Got my vote anyway.