# Using Data Annotations to define which attribute should be used as DropDown Text?

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I have the following model:

```
public class Bus
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string From { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string To { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Label { get; set; }

    }
```

When I do:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BusID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

the dropdown text label is the 'From' attribute.

I'm wondering if there is any way via data annotations to define which field to be used as 'Text' when rendering a drop down?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this question: [how to choose displayed Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063846/how-to-choose-displayed-text-on-html-dropdownlistfor)

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the used Property by Data Annotations, but you can do it with the DropDownListFor-Method, as in my comment referred.